# Issues with CAPlayThrough Example

Tags: macos, audio, device, capture

I am trying to learn Xcode Core Audio and stumbled upon this example:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CAPlayThrough/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004443

My intention is to capture the raw audio. Everytime I hit a break point, I lose the audio. Since it is using `CARingBuffer`.

1. How would you remove the time factor.I don't need real-time audio.
2. Since it is using `CARingBuffer` it should keep on writing to same memory location? So why don't I hear the audio? If I have a breakpoint?

I am reading the *Learning Core Audio* book. But, so far I cannot figure out this part of the following code:

```
CARingBufferError CARingBuffer::Store(const AudioBufferList *abl, UInt32 framesToWrite, SampleTime startWrite)
{
    if (framesToWrite == 0)
        return kCARingBufferError_OK;

    if (framesToWrite > mCapacityFrames)
        return kCARingBufferError_TooMuch;      // too big!

    SampleTime endWrite = startWrite + framesToWrite;

    if (startWrite < EndTime()) {
        // going backwards, throw everything out
        SetTimeBounds(startWrite, startWrite);
    } else if (endWrite - StartTime() <= mCapacityFrames) {
        // the buffer has not yet wrapped and will not need to
    } else {
        // advance the start time past the region we are about to overwrite
        SampleTime newStart = endWrite - mCapacityFrames;   // one buffer of time behind where we're writing
        SampleTime newEnd = std::max(newStart, EndTime());
        SetTimeBounds(newStart, newEnd);
    }

    // write the new frames
    Byte **buffers = mBuffers;
    int nchannels = mNumberChannels;
    int offset0, offset1, nbytes;
    SampleTime curEnd = EndTime();

    if (startWrite > curEnd) {
        // we are skipping some samples, so zero the range we are skipping
        offset0 = FrameOffset(curEnd);
        offset1 = FrameOffset(startWrite);
        if (offset0 < offset1)
            ZeroRange(buffers, nchannels, offset0, offset1 - offset0);
        else {
            ZeroRange(buffers, nchannels, offset0, mCapacityBytes - offset0);
            ZeroRange(buffers, nchannels, 0, offset1);
        }
        offset0 = offset1;
    } else {
        offset0 = FrameOffset(startWrite);
    }

    offset1 = FrameOffset(endWrite);
    if (offset0 < offset1)
        StoreABL(buffers, offset0, abl, 0, offset1 - offset0);
    else {
        nbytes = mCapacityBytes - offset0;
        StoreABL(buffers, offset0, abl, 0, nbytes);
        StoreABL(buffers, 0, abl, nbytes, offset1);
    }

    // now update the end time
    SetTimeBounds(StartTime(), endWrite);

    return kCARingBufferError_OK;   // success
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question well, the signal is lost while input unit (producer) being halted on a breakpoint. I presume this may be the expected behavior. CoreAudio is a ***pull-model*** engine running of the real time thread. This means under some conditions your producer hits a breakpoint, the ring buffer empties, the output unit (consumer) keeps on running, but gets nothing from the buffer while the playthrough chain is interrupted, hence the possible silence.

Perhaps this code from the example is not really the simplest one: I see it also zeroes audio buffers if ring buffer gets overrun/underrun, AFAICT.
The term *"raw audio"* in the question is also not self-explanatory, I'm not sure what does it mean. I would suggest trying to learn async i/o using simpler circular buffers. There are few of them (without obligatory time values) on GitHub.

Please also be so kind to format the source code for easier reading.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When program hits the breakpoint,during the fetch operation I can still see the IOdata samples meaning the data samples are written to the memory stream. If that's the case why can't it play? am I missing something here? I will keep in mind to format any source code  I enter.

Comment: The code you are referring to isn't part of CoreAudio API itself, but of an example set of programs called _CoreAudio Public Utility_. They are not a "can't do without" for writing audio programs. BTW, there is no "IOdata" samples in the CAPlayThrough program, at least not in the version 1.2.2. I have. Make sure to remove all build optimizations if you want to see what's happening with the buffer data and feel something missing.

Comment: Please follow these steps: 1) Place breakpoint on CAPlayThrough.cpp Ling#699. Once it hits breakpoint stepinto and check IOdata changes its values. For remove all build optimization I followed these steps:Click your project name in the project navigator in the left pane under the folder icon. 2.Click 'Build Settings' on the top menu. 3.Scroll down to 'Apple LLVM 6.0 - Code Generation' 4.Under 'Optimization Level' Select 'None [-O0]'

Comment: I don't see a problem in `inline void MakeBufferSilent (AudioBufferList *ioData){ …}`, so I'm afraid I can't help. Thanks for asking nevertheless.